# R Markdown not knitting when I add a new plot

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

My R markdown file is working fine, until I add a particular plot, then it will not knit and displays the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error:  File `filename_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-2-1' not found.
```

When I remove the plot, the file knits, when i include it, it doesn't knit.  Here is the code I'm using for the plot:

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
plot(x=variable1,y=variable2,main="plot title")
```
````

I'm at a loss as to why this isn't working, when I've got other plots in the document that are displaying fine and are knitting in the pdf.

Comment: what is `variable1` and `variable2`?  Are they vectors

Comment: Are you able to run the plot without knitting?

Comment: I'm able to run the plot without knitting, and I can also knit the plot on it's own in another document.  Basically, I've managed to get around it by starting an entire new document, copying all of the text into the new document, then kitting and it has (rather annoyingly) worked

Comment: Further to this - the error starting randomly occurring again - I got around this by rebooting my laptop and then starting a new file.  Annoyingly, the issue just randomly starts, sometimes, when I changed one text character (to nothing innocuous). When I revert the text to its prior state, it works again.  The reboot method seems to be working as a short-term solution, however, in the long-term, this is definitely not ideal.  I think I'll probably stick to using Overleaf.

Answer (score 0):

Rather frustratingly, I have managed to get around the issue by copying all of the text into a new document, and then trying to knit, and it worked straight away... However, after a while, the same issue kept occurring, this time with a different plot.  A further workaround seemed to be rebooting the laptop.  Again, I'm not entirely sure what is causing the issue, but it was occurring intermittently and without warning.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with one document with the following error

Error:
! impossible d'ouvrir le fichier 'Analyse_googleform_2023_05_15.Presentiel.Module_deb.CD_UM_eng_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-2-1.pdf'

For some reason, naming the chunk made the knit working.